# How to build SpringBoot JAR and run it when project runs using a very long script?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I'm on Spring Boot 2.2.4.

Currently, I'm running my project with a very long command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/home/jarvis/Downloads/ideaIU-2021.3.1-no-jbr/idea-IU-213.6461.79/lib/idea_rt.jar=35569:/home/jarvis/Downloads/ideaIU-2021.3.1-no-jbr/idea-IU-213.6461.79/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/jarvis

--------- PATH TO A LOT OF DEPENDENCY JARS-------------

/IdeaProjects/Blockchain_Microservice/backend/target/classes:/home/jarvis/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-vision/1.99.3/google-cloud-vision-1.99.3.jar:/home/jarvis/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-api/1.30.2/grpc-api-1.30.2.jar:/home/jarvis/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar com.bcmicroservice.spring.jwt.mongodb.SpringBootSecurityJwtMongodbApplication
```

This command is generated when I click the triangular `play button` on `@SpringBootApplication`. My code is running fine with this, but the problem is I can't create a JAR using this. Can you please tell me how to create a JAR from this so I can deploy it on my cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot  This will allow you to bundle your dependencies so that all you need is the right version of java.

Comment: Spring Boot does that automatically for you when you are using the proper maven or gradle plugin. So if you are using the proper tools and setup this should work out-of-the-box, if not you haven't setup things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a fat jar/war as Taylor said in a comment, then you can put all the jvm directives on a conf file with the same name on your jar in the same directory of your jar file.

If your jar name is my-project.jar your conf file will be my-project.conf and his content will be :

JAVA_OPTS="all-your-java-opts"